# Is $x^{1/x}$ is continuous at $x=0$ if not which type of discontinuity does it have?

Tags: calculus, limits

I have a function 
$f(x)=x^{1/x}$ to check whether continuous at $x=0$ or not

$$\lim_{x\to 0}x^{1/x}=\exp \lim_{x\to 0}\frac1x\ln x=?$$
I got stuck here to find the limit of function

Although I know that function $x^{1/x}$ is not defined at $x=0$ but how to find its limit.

Please help me.

Comment: First, it is defined only for $x>0$. Second, what is the limit of $\frac{\ln x}x$ when $x\to 0^+$?

Comment: "I have a function f(x)=x1/x to check whether continuous at x=0"  If it's not defined at $x=0$ it can't be continuous at $x =0$.  End of story.  "I got stuck here to find the limit of function"  Why do you want to find the limit? You  know $\lim_{x\to 0} f(x) \ne f(0)$ because $f(0)$ is not defined.  So why do you care what $\lim_{x\to 0}f(0)$ is?

Comment: "Although I know that function x1/x is not defined at x=0 "  and therefore it is not continuous at $x=0$.  "but how to find its limit" Who's asking you to? Are they paying you money?  You already showed them that $f(x)$ is not continuous at $x=0$.  If they wanted to know more they should have asked for it.  If they want to know what the $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)$ is charge them extra.

Answer (score 4):

Observe that from the positive side of $0$,
\begin{align}
\lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{\ln(x)}{x} &= -\infty\\
\Rightarrow \lim_{x \to 0^+} \exp\left(\frac{\ln(x)}{x}\right) &= 0
\end{align}
whereas
\begin{align}
\lim_{x \to 0^-} \frac{\ln(x)}{x} &= \lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{i\ln(x)}{-x}\\
\Rightarrow \lim_{x \to 0^-} \exp\left(\frac{\ln(x)}{x}\right) &= \lim_{x \to -\infty} \left(\cos(x) + i\sin(x)\right)
\end{align} 
which doesn't converge.

So our domain is really important here. If we're looking at $x \in (0,\infty)$ then $x^{1/x}$ certainly has a continuous extension onto $[0,\infty)$ by defining the function to be $0$ at $x = 0$.